# d3js using an attribute that is updated within the same callback

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As part of a larger project, I'm wanting to update an attribute of an SVG line from within a click handler and then subsequently use that attribute while still within the callback.  I'm new at d3 and don't have a lot of experience with javascript so I suspect that I may have some basic misunderstanding about how this works within the language.

I've distilled it down to a simple example:

```
var lines = [
   { "x1": 50, "y1": 50, "x2": 350, "y2": 150 },
   { "x1": 50, "y1": 150, "x2": 350, "y2": 50 }
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 200);

var lines = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(lines)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x1;})
    .attr("y1", function(d){return d.y1;})
    .attr("x2", function(d){return d.x2;})
    .attr("y2", function(d){return d.y2;})
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("stroke", "#00b000");

lines.on("click", function ()  {

    svg.selectAll("line")
        .attr("val", 10);

    svg.selectAll("line")
        .attr("stroke", "#b000b0")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.val; });
});
```

I've created it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d_chord/AwWwB/) to demonstrate.

In the on click handler, I'm updating the "val" attribute and then trying to use that attribute to set the stroke-width.  My expectation is that when clicking the lines, the stroke width will change to 10, but instead it appears to change to 1.

Is there a way to make this work?  I understand that in this simple example I could just set stroke-width to 10 directly, but I'd like to understand why I can't use the val attribute from within that function.

Also, recommendations for better style in any part of this are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'val'` you're setting via the `attr` function becomes an attribute of the `<line>` element –– not of the model `d` that is bound to it. So `d.val` is `undefined`, which is why the stroke is unaffected.

So you need to get that attribute value from the `<line>` element itself. To get hold of that element from inside that function (the one you're using to set `stroke-width`), you need to call `d3.select(this)`, which creates a d3 selection containing that element (which is `this` inside that function).

Then to get its `val` attribute, you need to call `attr('val')` on that d3 selection. When you call `attr` with a single, string param it acts as a getter, rather than a setter, so it'll return the `10` you set on it.

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
.attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d3.select(this).attr('val'); });
```

Comment: This answer is the exact solution for this problem.  Thank you very much!  This actually helps in my understanding of d3 in general.